# Property 'clearRect' does not exist on type 'HTMLCanvasElement'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, canvas

canvas has type HTMLCanvasElement | null

when i call clearRect method in canvas then i get this error:

Property 'clearRect' does not exist on type 'HTMLCanvasElement'.

```
this.canvas?.clearRect()
```

I dont know how solve this problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it doesn't exists on `HTMLCanvasElement`.

It exists on `CanvasRenderingContext2D`

```
if (this.canvas) {
  const ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect();
}
```